# ССП с союзом "И" -- запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

Предложение

> Мой начальник видит мою усидчивость(,) и больше ему от меня ничего не надо.

является ССП с союзом "И" и в нем нет общих членов, так что по правилам в нем должна стоять запятая. Но мой внутренний голос настоятельно требует убрать ее, не объясняя толком причин. Только что-то невнятное вроде того, что это одна смысловая единица и разрывать ее нельзя. Есть ли у этого внутреннего голоса какие-нибудь основания для такого требования или я могу со спокойной совестью его проигнорировать?

Comment: Никаких оснований убирать запятую нет. Так что гоните внутренний голос прочь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, внутренний голос надо всегда слушать :))

Что же в оформлении предложения не так? Пожалуй, отношения между двумя высказываниями при наличии союза И выглядят неопределенно, так как  **союз *И*** довольно обобщенный и **неоднозначный**.

Здесь же хочется выразить **взаимообусловленность** двух фраз, обозначив присоединительный характер второго сообщения, и это можно сделать с помощью тире:

*Мой начальник видит мою усидчивость – **больше ему от меня ничего не надо**.*

Так предложение выглядит намного динамичнее, чем вялый и неопределенный исходный вариант.

Впрочем, вопрос дискуссионный.

Comment: Верно! Так и сделаю. Спасибо!